# Check if directory has changed

Tags: linux, bash, directory

I am working on a backup script and I've got a problem. I would like to backup my documents to a ftp server. Because I don't like encfs so I try to realise this by using z-zip and encrypted archives. This is working well but I would like to create a new archive only when a file inside a subdirectory has changed so lftp is only uploading the changed ones.

My codesnippet looks like this:

```
cd /mnt/HD_a2/documents
for i in */
do 7za a -t7z /mnt/HD_a2/encrypted/ul_doc/"${i%/}.7z" -p1234 -mhe "$i" 
done
```

How can I change this code so it's only creating a new archive when a file inside "i" has been changed within the last 7 days? (This script is executed by cron every 7 days)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, [Barmar`s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21133346/2698019) is almost right, but it does not count files correctly. I've looked around for other similar questions  and it seems like it is a common mistake(*please note that it is not critical for his solution, but it might confuse other programmers if they touch it, because it does not what most people will expect*), no one is accounting the fact that filenames can contain newlines. So here is a bit better version that gives you the right file count:

```
for i in */
do
    fileCount=$(find "$i" -type f -mtime -8 -exec printf . \;)
    if (( ${#fileCount} > 0 )); then
        7za a -t7z /mnt/HD_a2/encrypted/ul_doc/"${i%/}.7z" -p1234 -mhe "$i" 
    fi
done
```

But what if you have thousands of files? That would build a string that is exactly as long as the number of your files.

So we can use this:

```
for i in */
do
    fileCount=$(find "$i" -type f -mtime -8 -exec printf . \; | wc -c)
    if (( fileCount > 0 )); then
        7za a -t7z /mnt/HD_a2/encrypted/ul_doc/"${i%/}.7z" -p1234 -mhe "$i" 
    fi
done
```

Or this:

```
for i in */
do
    fileCount=$(find "$i" -type f -mtime -8 -exec echo \; | wc -l)
    if (( fileCount > 0 )); then
        7za a -t7z /mnt/HD_a2/encrypted/ul_doc/"${i%/}.7z" -p1234 -mhe "$i" 
    fi
done
```

Hoping that useless string data is not going to be cached.

**But we only need to know if there is AT LEAST one file, we don't have to count all of them!** This way we can stop immediately if something was found.

```
for i in */
do
    fileFound=$(find "$i" -type f -mtime -8 | head -n 1)
    if [[ $fileFound ]]; then
        7za a -t7z /mnt/HD_a2/encrypted/ul_doc/"${i%/}.7z" -p1234 -mhe "$i" 
    fi
done
```

That's it. This solution will work MUCH faster because it does not have to look for other files and it does not even have to check their `mtime`. Try running this code without `head` and you'll notice a significant difference - from several hours to less than a second for my home folder. (I'm not even sure if it will ever manage to finish it on my pc, I have millions of small files in my home folder...)

Comment: Why do you need to count the files correctly? All that matters is zero or non-zero.

Comment: @Barmar Did you really read my answer till the end? Yes, but many programmers might assume blindly that ``wc -l`` is going to give them correct number of files, so I wanted to clarify that(and you'll rarely see this correct solution for counting files). Later, in the end of my answer, I gave an even better solution to see if there is at least one file.

Comment: Luckily `find` doesn't buffer its output, or that solution would still examine lots of files before exiting.

Comment: your last solution is working like a charm, thank you very much!

Comment: @Barmar I'm pretty sure that it does buffer its output, as well as it does check if stdout is writable or not.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in */
do 
    if [ `find "$i" -type f -mtime -7 | wc -l` -gt 0 ]
    then 7za a -t7z /mnt/HD_a2/encrypted/ul_doc/"${i%/}.7z" -p1234 -mhe "$i" 
    fi
done
```

Comment: What about files with newlines?

Comment: This will work for them. It doesn't use the filenames, it just checks if `find` lists any filenames.

Comment: Exactly, but it is still very inefficient because it has to check the ``mtime`` of all files. See my answer for a better solution

Comment: thank you, wrote down both solutions so it's a good exercise for me :)